# explode query parameters and values with ampersand but ignore it if only between numbers in javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, regex, laravel

my case is this i have a a javascript string which contains parameters and values and i want to post them to php but i want to convert them to array with explode them delimiter '&' and i have one value contains ampersand looks like this "10168829280&65685254|10170185230&65412764" this value is only bunch of numbers separated by bars .

so i want a method in javascript or php to explode and ignore ampersand between numbers and thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
var s = "10168829280&65685254|10170185230&65412764"
console.log(s.replace(/(?<=\d+)&(?=\d+)/mg, ""));
```

Comment: it works thank you so much